# SQLITE compare columns in two tables to find LIKE data

Tags: linux, sqlite, compare

I am trying to compare data in one column that is in two different tables.  The two tables are a lot more columns, but for simplicity.....

```
CREATE TABLE A(
ID     integer   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name   char(20)
);


CREATE TABLE B(
ID     integer   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name   char(20)
);

INSERT INTO A(name) VALUES ('John Smith');
INSERT INTO A(name) VALUES ('J Doe');
INSERT INTO A(name) VALUES ('Jane Smith');

INSERT INTO B(name)VALUES('John Smith');
INSERT INTO B(name)VALUES('J. Doe');
INSERT INTO B(name)VALUES('jane smith');
```

Most of what I've found so far has been to find the differences between tables, but I haven't managed to find how to match up similar data.  I am looking for something that will yield results like this:

**Table A**           |     **Table B**

John Smith    |    John Smith

Jane Smith    |   jane smith

J Doe           |   J. Doe

The following code matched up several names:

```
 CREATE TABLE tblC (
 tblAName    char(20),
 tblBName    char(20)
 );

 INSERT INTO tblC ( tblAName, tblBName) 

 SELECT 
 tblA.name,
 tblB.name 

 FROM tblA 
 LEFT JOIN on tblB WHERE tblA.name LIKE tblB.name;
```

However, I haven't figured out how to get the names that contain punctuation.  This didn't work:

```
 INSERT INTO tblC (tblAName, tblBName) 

 SELECT 
 tblA.name,
 tblB.name 

 FROM tblA 
 LEFT JOIN on tblB WHERE tblA.name LIKE tblB.name
 WHERE tblA.name LIKE "%Xxx%" OR "%X.%" tblB.name LIKE "%Xxx%" OR "%X.%";
```

Comment: Define "similar".

Comment: By similar I mean that if table A has "John Smith" in the name field, I want it to match to be able B where the name field contains "JOHN SMITH", JOHN_SMITH", "JohnSmith", etc.

Comment: You have listed a few examples, but nothing that would allow to specify an algorithm.

Comment: I took another look at the data and realized there actually aren't as many variables as I previously thought.  I'm going to edit my original question to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore certain characters, remove them with [replace()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) before doing the comparisons. To ignore case, use LIKE, or [COLLATE](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) NOCASE:

```
SELECT A.name,
       B.name
FROM A
JOIN B ON replace(A.name, '.', '') LIKE
          replace(B.name, '.', '');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  I would have never thought to use "replace".  Thank you!   I also changed "INSERT INTO..." to "INSERT OR IGRNORE INTO..." and set both name fields to NOT NULL so it ignores any records where there isn't a matching/similar name in both tables.